# How do I manage users in ProFTPD?

Tags: configuration, ftp, authentication

How do i add a new user to my FTP server running ProFTPD. 
I have the server running, i added a system user but i get  Login incorrect.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Do you have virtual users enabled?

Comment: Did you set a password for that user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If normal system users are used, you simply use the system utilities: adduser, usermod, useradd, userdem, deluser, etc

If virtual users are enabled the users are managed in the file defined by the AuthUserFile directive and the groups in AuthGroupFile. The format is similar to the system passwd file and group file. You can learn more at http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/VirtualUsers.html